# How to Notify one component is created ,then only create a new component in Blazor

Tags: blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I think I am asking a simple question, but I don't know how to do this.
Currently, I am working on the Blazor server application and this question is regarding the components of blazor server.I have created a page called pageA and created a component called componentA inside pageA.
as well as I have created a page called pageB and created the componentB inside pageB.

pageA.razor

```
<h3>pageA<h3>
<componentA/>
@*do some stuff*@
```

pageB.razor

```
<h3>pageB<h3>
<componentB/>
@*do some stuff*@
```

Now my requirement is to create the componentB after creating componentA. I have an idea to do that. what it is first we have to notify componentB that the componentA has been created and after we have to start the creating componentB. I don't know whether my idea is correct or wrong. Anybody who knows about this please help me. appreciate all your helps.

Comment: You don't manually create components - they are created for you when they are needed.

Comment: but can't I do this? I am not going to create components manually. the componentB should be created by the code itself after creating the componentA. can't I even notify  componentB that the componentA is created and now componentB can render??

Comment: You said they are on different "pages" - how and why would you expect B to be instantiated while A is active?

Comment: Are you trying to create a multi-step "wizard" component?

Comment: if those components are on the same page, can it be done ??

because I have 2 components on the same page. but my issue is if one component is loaded my second component is not loaded, if the second one is loaded the first one is not loading. So I need to expect componentB to be instantiated while componentA is active . i just add this different page case.it is not compulsory .

Comment: Share some actual realistic code - there is no way to know what you are doing